# Render Name value list using rendering variant fields

Tags: sxa, presentation

Is there any way to render  Name value list field using rendering variant fields?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to achieve. If you will use standard Variant Field you will see something like this:

[image]

for such field:

[image]

If you want to have a more fancy look & feel I would suggest writing your own Variant Token. A sample implementation can look like this:

```
public class ResolveNameValueList : ResolveVariantTokensProcessor
{
    public override string Token => "$nameValueList";

    public override void ResolveToken(ResolveVariantTokensArgs args)
    {
        string content = GetContent(args);

        if (args.ResultControl != null)
        {
            args.ResultControl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl
            {
                Text = content
            });
        }
        else
        {
            args.Result = content;
        }
    }

    protected virtual string GetContent(ResolveVariantTokensArgs args)
    {
        string content = string.Empty;

        var field = args.ContextItem.Fields["List"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(field?.Value))
        {
            CustomField customField = FieldTypeManager.GetField(field);
            if (customField is NameValueListField)
            {
                NameValueListField nameValueList = customField as NameValueListField;
                foreach (string key in nameValueList.NameValues.Keys)
                {
                    content += $"<div>{key}: {nameValueList.NameValues[key]}</div>";
                }

            }
        }

        return content;
    }
}
```

And registration:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <resolveVariantTokens>
                <processor type="YOUR_NAMESPACE.ResolveNameValueList, YOUR_ASSEMBLY" resolve="true" />
            </resolveVariantTokens>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

With such token, you only need to create a new Variant Token item and specify your custom token name:

[image]

This will give you:

[image]

**Last note:** Maybe this would be possible in NVelocity templates but do not go that path. If there is a different way (even if requires writing some code) to achieve something without NVelocty - go for it!